# Assign string uint8_t

Tags: c++, string, pointers, uint8t

I am struggling to use a `uint8_t*` to point the first field of a string.

This is how my code looks like

```
std::string data1
uint8_t* data

data = (uint8_t*)data1[0]
```

What is wrong here? When I run it it crashed

Thanks in advance

Comment: your code isn't actually compilable

Comment: If you have to use a cast you are *usually* doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3):

`data[0]` returns a reference to the first `char` in the string (provided the string is not empty, otherwise the return value is undefined).  You are type-casting the **value** of that `char` to a pointer.  So, your code crashes when it tries to use the pointer to access an invalid memory address.  You need to type-cast the **address** of that `char` instead:

```
data = (uint8_t*) &data1[0];
```

Or, in a more C++-ish (and safer) manner:

```
data = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&data1[0]);
```

Or, with bounds checking:

```
data = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&(data1.at(0)));
```

Answer (score 2):

For what you want to do you could try:

```
data = (uint8_t*)data1.c_str();
```

Don't know exactly what are you trying to achieve, but there is for sure a better approach.

Comment: Be careful, because `c_str()` returns a `const char*`, and you are casting away the `const` in a C-ish manner instead of a C++-ish manner. The C++ way would be more like this: `data = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(const_cast<char*>(data1.c_str()));` Also, before C++11, there was no guarantee that `c_str()` actually returned a pointer to the internal data of the `std::string` (though that was a common implementation for simplicity). C++11 onward guarantees it. C++17 later added a non-`const` version of the `data()` method: `data = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(data1.data());`

Answer (score 2):

For example if you are doing something like :

```
std::string data1 = "One"
```

then data1[0] gives 'O' whose ASCII value is 79.
Now you use this 79 as an address.

So, the pointer named data has value 79 in it.

So when you use this pointer in your code again, you are actually attempting to read or write protected memory(0x0000004F or 79). Hence, its crashes at run time.